# How to use connection string with EntityFrameworkCore 3 in an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, entity-framework-core-3.1

So I'm using the following code to configure my DbContext in the FunctionsStartup's Configure method:

```
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services.AddOptions();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);

        builder.Services.Configure<MessageResenderOptions>(config);
        builder.Services.PostConfigure<MessageResenderOptions>(opt =>
            opt.ServiceBusConnectionString = config["ServiceBusConnectionString"]);

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<BackOfficeFacadeDatabaseContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnectionString")));
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository.Repository>();
```

The "DatabaseConnectionString" is provided in the Azure Deployment, and is visible in the Azure Portal Configuration section of the function.

But my function can't connect to the database. Whenever I provide the ConnectionString hardcoded it works just fine, but when I try and fetch it as above it does not connect. I've checked the actual value of the connection string in the config section of the function and it is correct.

I think it has to do with a timing issue. You can see in the code above that the ServiceBusConnectionString is provided in a Services.PostConfigure method which is not the case for the DbContext. So I figured I need to somehow inject the DbContext in a "PostConfigure" manner, but I did not succeed.

Really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, ignore this. I had the wrong connection string in my app settings..